# How to linearize a reciprocating motion using a motor control circuit

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, motor-controller

I have a reciprocating machine that uses a variant of the [Scotch yoke](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_yoke) mechanism. This produces a sinusoidal motion at a 15 mm stroke.

For my application, I need this motion to have approximately linear velocity throughout the motion. I plan to operate this machine at about 10 Hz with a fixed mass.

My first idea was to vary the voltage to the motor using a sine wave. I would just need a single Hall-effect sensor to measure the phase of the motion path so I could synchronize the signal.

I've read that directly driving a motor like this can be very inefficient, but I should be well below the rated load of my motor, so I don’t think this would be an issue. However, I’m not sure if this will give me what I want because it seems the momentum of the system could cause an asymmetry.

The other option is a PWM controller, but it seems like this would be more difficult to tune. I’m also not sure if I could vary the speed fast enough and with enough precision using PWM.

Comment: Your word 'approximately' is doing a lot of heavy lifting, in fact it pretty much renders the rest of your speculation moot. The differential at the peaks is zero to near zero, which means that even at very high motor speed, the link speed will drop to zero. Specify how linear the speed should be over what range of the stroke. The motor needs to handle a lot of power to change speed rapidly. The speed / applied voltage should be the inverse of a cosine wave, open loop may do, or you might need closed loop to meet your specified accuracy.

Comment: I’m dividing the stroke into 16 segments and I need each segment to be as close to equal length as possible. The ends don’t matter too much, I can have a small dead region on either end if I have to.

Comment: well you have to. How much motor power you have to provide near the ends is very dependent on the size of the dead zone. Less dead zone, more power required.

Comment: I had to look up "scottish yoke": basically a rotating pin pushing a slider: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_yoke)

Comment: Apologies for the typo, I’ve edited the post accordingly.

Comment: This might be a better question for [Engineering Stackexchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/), where you would also get answers from mechanical engineers. For example, using an oblong gear instead of a circular one might get you close enough to "linear" motion without needing any fancy electronics.

Comment: When you say linear velocity, do you mean that the mass (load) has constant speed during a forward stroke, and then reverses to have the same constant speed going backwards?

Answer (score 0):

Choose a stepper motor with enough torque to work in your application, then drive it with just about any open-source stepper motor controller. Then just program it with a velocity profile derived from the geometry of the system. It will be easy and cheap. In principle, any 3D printer control board would do this, without any extra hardware. An index detector would be needed to "home" the stepper once to fix the relationship between the electrical and mechanical angle. Then in principle you could just feed it a long gcode file with the trajectory you want, running on repeat. In Marlin it's easy enough to have the firmware self-generate the gcode loop, so you wouldn't need any external files.

I've done roughly a similar thing to wind thin magnet wire on a rectangular former. The motor was a synchronous two-phase motor I had laying around, and I drove the power stage (2 x H-bridge) from a Raspberry Pico. It was running open loop, on a pre-determined angular velocity profile. Worked well enough not to rip the wire. It was AWG 40 or AWG 42 IIRC.